# length of sum of two submodule

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be a $R$-module with finite length and $K$ and $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Prove that 
$l(K+N)+l(K\cap N)=l(K)+l(N)$.

My proof: First, by assuming that $K\cap N=\{0\}$, we can conclude that $l(K+N)=l(K)+l(N)$.

The detail: Let $n=l(K)$ and $m=l(N)$.
Let $\{0\}\subseteq K_0\subsetneq K_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq K_n=K$ be a composition series of $K$. Let $\{0\}\subseteq N_0\subsetneq N_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq N_m=N$ be a composition series of $N$. 
Define $\phi: K \rightarrow K+N $ by $\phi(k)=k$ and $\psi:K+N \rightarrow N$ by $\psi(k+n)=n$. For $0 \leq i \leq n$, let $M_i=\phi(K_i)$ and for $n+1\leq i\leq n+m$, let $M_i=\psi^{-1}(N_i)$, then $\{M_i\}_{i=0}^{n+m}$ be a composition series for $K+N$. Hence, $l(K+N)=n+m=l(K)+l(N)$.

Could you help me proving the general cases, that is $K\cap N \neq \{0\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second isomorphism theorem says we have an exact sequence

$$0 \to K \cap N \to  K  \to (K+ N)/N \to 0$$

and so $l(K) = l(K\cap N) + l\left( K+N/N\right) = l(K \cap N)+ l(K+N) - l(N)$ . Thus

$$l(K) + l(N) = l(K \cap N) + l(K+N).$$

Comment: How to show that l((K+N)/N)=l(K+N)-l(N)?

Comment: Consider the exact sequence $0 \to N \to K+N \to (K+N)/N\to 0$

Comment: thanks BenjaLim, i will try work on it. But could we prove this without exact sequence concept, instead of directly from definition of composition series?

Comment: @beginner I would suggest proving the following. Suppose that $M$ is a module of finite length. Then for any ses $0 \to N \to M \to L \to 0$, we have $N,L$ of finite length too. In this case, $l(M) = l(N) + l(L)$.

Comment: @beginner Do you mean "with the definition of composition series" and not "instead of"? Your original post seems to make that seem the case...

Comment: @rschwieb: But I only prove the cases $K \cap N =\{0\}$

Comment: @beginner I'm just trying to clarify your comment, since it seems to be incomprehensible. At any rate, the solution I offered only deals with the definition of composition series.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Consider $(K+N)/K$. If you have a composition series for this module, then it can "stack on top of" a composition series of $K$ to make a composition series for $K+N$.

Hint 2: By an isomorphism theorem, $(N+K)/K\cong N/(N\cap K)$.

Hint 3: Convince yourself that $\ell(M/N)=\ell(M)-\ell(N)$, (at least when all the lengths are finite.)

Comment: for case that $M$ be a R-module with $INFINITE$ length . is this true?

Comment: Since arithmetic using infinities is undefined, the equation is meaningless in that case.  I imagine that it's possible to create examples $M$ and $N$ to have infinite length, and $M/N$ to have either infinite or finite length.